# How can I change individual sampling point colour based on the RGB values?

Tags: qgis, qgis-processing

I have three sampling points (A, B, and C) with their respective latitude and longitude information. Additionally, I have three columns for each sampling point representing R, G and B values (the sum of RGB is 255). Now, How can I display the individual sampling colour with their respective RGB values?

Answer (score 1):

You only have three points so set the RGB values in the Select Color section of the layers symbology.

To access the Select Color dialog right click the layer in the Layers Pane, Select Properties, Select Symbology, click the color bar.
[image]